Program not running using singularity but works in docker
I have the following Docker recipe which works fine with Docker:
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1-noble
LABEL maintainer="ramiro.barrantes@med.uvm.edu"
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -c bioconda -c conda-forge fastQC
RUN micromamba clean --all --yes
ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/conda/bin

If I build it and run it with Docker it works fine
docker build -t test .
docker tag test:latest rbarrant/test:0.1
docker push rbarrant/test:0.1

docker run rbarrant/test:0.1 fastqc --help

But with singularity it complains:
singularity exec docker://rbarrant/test:0.1 fastqc


INFO:    Using cached SIF image Can't locate FindBin.pm in @INC (you
may need to install the FindBin module) (@INC entries checked:
/etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.38.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.38
/usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.38 /usr/share/perl/5.38
/usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /opt/conda/bin/fastqc line 4. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at /opt/conda/bin/fastqc line 4.

What am I missing?

Added an answer. Did you try to install perl with the command below?

I did, no success. This works with docker but not with singularity.

I got it, just need to add PERL5LIB as an environment variable.
ENV PERL5LIB=/opt/conda/lib/perl5/core_perl/

Again, this is not needed for Docker, but it is for singularity. Hence the recipe would be:
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1-noble
LABEL maintainer="ramiro.barrantes@med.uvm.edu"
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -c bioconda -c conda-forge fastQC
ENV PERL5LIB=/opt/conda/lib/perl5/core_perl/
RUN micromamba clean --all --yes
ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/conda/bin


Try to add the line below to your Dockerfile, it will install perl:
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -c conda-forge perl


The problem isn't perl? I did this and I got the same error. I think it has to do with where it is looking for libraries, otherwise, why would it work with docker but not with singularity.
